# Delays in UI display in QT Multithreading

Tags: qt, qthread

I have a multi-threaded application. My application has 2 dialogs: Main Dialog (`Dialog1`) and Transaction Dialog (`Dialog2`). When the application runs, `Dialog1` will start a `QThread` to download a big file. While downloading, `Dialog2` will be displayed. `Dialog2` will display the status of the download. Note that the download will still continue even if `Dialog2` is displayed. When `Dialog2` is displayed, a poller thread will be started. This thread will process the transaction when a card is detected.

Problem:
When the card is detected, `Dialog2` should update the UI (I used signal and slot for this). However, updating the UI is delayed. or it takes several seconds to display the correct message to the UI. This only happens when download is ongoing.

Below is my code:

#### Dialog1:

```
void Dialog1::startDownlaod()
{
    DownloadClass *downloadClass ;

    Dialog2 *dialog2 = new Dialog2 (this);

    cout << "[Dialog2] from main thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;

    downloadClass = new DownloadClass ();

    pAppDownloadThread_ = nullptr;
    pAppDownloadThread_ = new QThread();
    downloadClass->moveToThread(pAppDownloadThread_);
    connect(pAppDownloadThread_, SIGNAL(started()), downloadClass , SLOT(processDownloadRequest()));
    connect(downloadClass , SIGNAL(finished()), pAppDownloadThread_, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(downloadClass , SIGNAL(finished()), downloadClass , SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(pAppDownloadThread_, SIGNAL(finished()), pAppDownloadThread_, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(downloadClass , SIGNAL(updateDownloadStatus()), dialog2, SLOT(updateDownloadStatus()));

    pAppDownloadThread_->start();

    dialog2->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog2->exec();
}
```

#### Downloader class:

```
class DownloadClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void processDownloadRequest();

signals:
    void finished();
    void onUpdateDownloadStatus();
}
```

#### Dialog2:

```
// this is the slot that will update downlaod status
void Dialog2::updateDownloadStatus()
{
    ui->labelStatus.setText("some text here");
}

// this is method to start the poller thread
void Dialog2::startPollingThread()
{   
    pollingThread_ = new QThread;

    Poller::instance()->moveToThread(pollingThread_); // singleton

    connect(pollingThread_, SIGNAL(started()), Poller::instance(), SLOT(poll()));
connect(Notifier::getInstance(), SIGNAL(displayMessage(QString)), this, SLOT(displayMessage(QString)));
    connect(Poller::instance(), SIGNAL(finished()), pPollingThread_, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(pPollingThread_, SIGNAL(finished()), Poller::instance(), SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(pPollingThread_, SIGNAL(finished()), pPollingThread_, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    cout << "[Dialog2] from main thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;
    pollingThread_->start();
}
```

#### Poller class:

```
class Poller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void poll();

signals:
    void finished();
    void displayMessage(QString message);
}

// poll() method
void Poller::poll()
{
    if(isCardDetected)
        emit displayMessage("Detected"); // this will be sent to Dialog2 to display the message in the label
    else
        emit displayMessage("No card detected");
}
```

Here is the output when I print the threadID:

```
[Dialog2] from main thread: 0xb6fed000
[Dialog1] from main thread: 0xb6fed000
[Poller] from poller thread: 0xb0aff400
[DownloadClass] from downloader class: 0xb02ff400
```

Notice that `threadID` of `Dialog1` and `Dialog2` are the same.

Comment: You state `"Problem: When the card is detected..."`:  what card?  Which piece of code is supposed to trigger the update in `Dialog2`?  You probably need to show the implementation/usage of `Poller`.  Also note that you have `connect(downloadClass , SIGNAL(updateDownloadStatus()), ...` but your `DownloadClass` type has no such signal defined.

Comment: I edited my code. the card I used is a smart card